# How to navigate through xml nodes in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml

How can I navigate xml nodes using jQuery without using `hide() and show()` methods. Only replacing the nodes with next and previous sibilings using next, previous buttons like [THIS](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_app_navigate)

I have my demo here created in [PLUNKER DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/2fz8cKfXsKYl6wDlLzgz?p=preview) 
 I used `hide() and show()`. I can see in the debugger displaying it as display none and block which I dont like to use. I want to use navigation like w3schools [DEMO](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_app_navigate). Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/adN3t2rDooLDJgWGYCXP?p=preview)

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var loadVar, numbOfElements=0, count, elementsPerPage = 5,
    currentPage, numberOfPage;

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: "data.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    contentType:"text/xml", 
    async:false,
    success: function(xml) {
      loadVar = xml;

      loadImages("ADOBE");
      showImages();
      disableEnableBtns();
    },

    error: function() {
      alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
    }
  });

  $("#adobe").click(function() {
    loadImages("ADOBE");
    showImages();
    disableEnableBtns();
  });

  $("#mac").click(function() {
    loadImages("MAC");
    showImages();
    disableEnableBtns();
  });

  var sTitle, countEach;

  function loadImages(loadNodeValues) {
    $("#thumbnails").empty();
    numbOfElements=0
    $(loadVar).find(loadNodeValues).each(function(i,item) { 
      var sTitle = "<section class='small count"+(i+1)+"'><h2>" +  $(item).find("CAPTION").text() +  "</h2><span>" +$(item).find("LINK").text() + "</span></section>";
      $("#thumbnails").html($("#thumbnails").html()+sTitle);
      numbOfElements++;
    });
    numberOfPage = numbOfElements / elementsPerPage;

  }

  function showImages() {
    $('.small').hide();
    for (i = 1; i <= elementsPerPage; i++) {
      $('.small').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('count' + i)) {
          $(this).show();
        }
      });
    }
    currentPage = 0;
  }

  function disableEnableBtns() {

    if (thumbnails.children.length <= elementsPerPage) {
      $("#rightBtn").prop("disabled", true);
      $("#leftBtn").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
      $("#rightBtn").prop("disabled", false);
      $("#leftBtn").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    $("#leftBtn").prop("disabled", true);
  }

  $("#rightBtn").click(function() {
    currentPage++;
    $('.small').hide();
    var limit = elementsPerPage * (currentPage + 1) > numbOfElements ? numbOfElements : elementsPerPage * (currentPage + 1);

    for (i = (currentPage * elementsPerPage) + 1; i <= limit ; i++) {

      $('.small').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('count' + i)) {
          $(this).show();
        } 
      });

if(i == numbOfElements)
          {
          $("#rightBtn").prop("disabled", true);
          $("#leftBtn").prop("disabled", false);
          }
          else
          {
       $("#rightBtn").prop("disabled", false);
          $("#leftBtn").prop("disabled", false);
          }
    }

  });

  $("#leftBtn").click(function() {
    currentPage--;
    $('.small').hide();
    for (i = (currentPage * elementsPerPage) + 1; i <= elementsPerPage * (currentPage + 1); i++) {
      $('.small').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('count' + i)) {
          $(this).show();
        } 
      });

          if(i == 5)
          {
          $("#rightBtn").prop("disabled", false);
          $("#leftBtn").prop("disabled", true);
          }
          else
          {
          $("#rightBtn").prop("disabled", false);
          $("#leftBtn").prop("disabled", false);
          }

    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing the previous, next and top link buttons issues.Can you help me with the navigation issue just by replacing nodes in 'elementsPerPage' without using hide() and show(). That would be great help.

Comment: Check this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HJKy8iYNX2CgUqJJM7IU?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I appreciate a lot. You just made my day! I learned something new too. You made with less lines of code too. Thanks once again.